# Combo Box Dropdown List from Table

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, datatables

First time creating forms to insert into a database.

I'm trying to create a drop down combo box that lists the entries in the second column...

[image]

This is in a seperate table. The issue I'm running into is how do I show what's in the `Description` column, but when I insert into the form, it's corresponding `PMRT_Need` value is put in the table.

The database is as such that it **HAS** to be the `PMRT_NEED` value unfortunately.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the **Row Source** to your appropriate table/query:

- Set the **Bound Column** to column `1` (i.e. the `PMRT_NEED` field)
- Set the **Column Count** to `2`
- Set the **Column Widths** to something like `0cm;5cm` (adjusting the second width to suit your data) such that the first column isn't displayed to the user.

This ensures that your combo box returns the value of the `PMRT_NEED` field for the selected item, but only the `Description` is displayed to the user.

Comment: For someone who prides myself on shortcuts, I never even got close to this one. Genius my friend!